# How to add Thrift dependencies to a C# project?

Tags: c#, thrift

Hi I'm trying to use Thrift for a project on Windows, however I don't seem to understand how to get it to work and I don't understand the documentation provided very well either. So far I managed to create the thrift compiler and use it to generate java and c# files. However, when it comes to using them in a simple project I seem to get stuck in the same part. Right now I'm following this tutorial:

http://blog.rfaisal.com/2013/10/09/getting-started-with-apache-thrift/

Which has been quite helpful but, I still don't understand how to add the language libraries, In the tutorial for instance he says:

"At this point, you need to add the thrift library to your project. Open the Thrift C# library from the tarball (should be under /lib/csharp) and compile it."

Later for the Client he says: 
"Copy the Thrift Java library from the tarball (should be under /lib/java) to this project."

I have both folders, but I'm unsure as of what exactly I should do.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's pretty broad, even though I answered below. You should narrow down the question to some specific issue where you run into trouble.

Comment: Divide Your problem to client side and server side.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear, I wanted to know what to add the language dependencies on my project. But it is now solved. Thank ou anyway

Comment: If I can give just one advice. Next time, please think a minute how you name the question. I am going to change the title accordingly (and then VTC as duplicate). Learn from it, but keep asking/contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was with adding the dependencies to the projects.

For c# one need to open the thrift solution, then select "Release" under build configurations and build it. Then under bin/Release you find the .dll file you need to reference in your project.

For java you need to add the whole org folder to your project and then you need to add the httpclient-version.jar and httpcore-version.jar to the build path

Comment: Well, how do I put it ... that's a general C# problem then. Of course you need to reference things that you intend to use.

Comment: Yeah but i had no idea what it was I needed to use, that was my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the [Apache Thrift web site](http://thrift.apache.org) which serves as a good start.

The Compiler comes prebuilt for Windows, so you theoretically do not need to build it on your own, but it isn't that hard either. At the end, that's a detail.

Regarding the libraries for C#, you have two options. The recommended one is to compile the Assembly using the project file under `/lib/csharp/src`. The other option is to simply include all the files into the project.

Of course, you only use the languages you need. If you want C# only, ignore Java. Thrift supports about 20+ languages on multiple platforms, you pick whatever you need and ignore the rest.

Same with the generated files: Either include them into the project or create an assembly, like it is done for the test under `lib/csharp/test/ThriftTest`.

The basic workflow is for all languages the same:

- create an IDL file to represent your API contract
- call the Thrift compiler to generate code
- put together the desired protocol/transport stack
- flesh out client and/or server code
- build everything
- be happy.

Comment: Thrift is nice library, my frst-time process was very smooth in C# & Java. I agree I'm happy. (except Delphi, but probably this language is ancient niche, dont compile because "unit socket")

Comment: @JacekCz: Not so ancient (we started with D2010), but a simple reason: As the maintainer of the Delphi bindings, I don't have all the Delphi versions on the market available for testing. If you could you provide a patch or PR for that issue I'd be glad to review it. See Thrift home page for [details on HowToContribute](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute)

Comment: @JacekCz: Just in case: I was serious about that. If you have a patch adressing that issue which you are legally allowed to contribute, please do it.

Comment: Now I have only occasionally contact with Borland/Embecadero at computer of my friend/business partner. few hours twice don't give resolution of compilation problem. I agree, Delphi has big difference between versions, we use two without success. This integration (for long-term delphi project) was done via SOAP, one technology capable for out Delphi.